# Attempting to change alignment of buttons in html

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align my row of buttons slightly lower than it currently is. However, since it's my first time learning html, I'm not exactly sure how to do it. I can align all the buttons together, but I cannot move the buttons as a whole.

```css
.button4 {
  display: inline-center;
  padding: 0.3em 1.0em;
  margin: 0 0.1em 0.4em 0;
  border: 0.15em solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-radius: 3em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0 0.04em 0.04em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

a.button4:hover {
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

@media all and (max-width:30em) {
  a.button4 {
    display: block;
    margin: 0.2em auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <a href="index.html" class="button4" style="background-color:#4e9af1">Introduction</a>
      <a href="privacy.html" class="button4" style="background-color:#4e9af1">Privacy Policy & Cookies/Security</a>
      <a href="security.html" class="button4" style="background-color:#4e9af1">Device Optimisation & Navigation</a>
      <a href="relevant-tech.html" class="button4" style="background-color:#4e9af1">Relevant Technologies</a>
      <a href="test-page.html" class="button4" style="background-color:#4e9af1">Web technologies</a>
      <a href="bibliography.html" class="button4" style="background-color:#4e9af1">Bibliography</a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should copy and paste your buttons html code also so we can look at the structure.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you want:

```
position:relative;
top:5px; //or whatever amount you want it to come down
```

and don't forget the "." before the "button4" in your CSS
. for classes, and # for IDs

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to set `display` to `inline-center`. You should use `inline-block` in this case

```css
.button4 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.3em 1.0em;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border: 0.15em solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-radius: 3em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0 0.04em 0.04em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

a.button4:hover {
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

@media all and (max-width:30em) {
  a.button4 {
    display: block;
    margin: 2em auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <a href="index.html" class="button4" style="background-color:#4e9af1">Introduction</a>
      <a href="privacy.html" class="button4" style="background-color:#4e9af1">Privacy Policy & Cookies/Security</a>
      <a href="security.html" class="button4" style="background-color:#4e9af1">Device Optimisation & Navigation</a>
      <a href="relevant-tech.html" class="button4" style="background-color:#4e9af1">Relevant Technologies</a>
      <a href="test-page.html" class="button4" style="background-color:#4e9af1">Web technologies</a>
      <a href="bibliography.html" class="button4" style="background-color:#4e9af1">Bibliography</a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `flexbox` which is widely supported.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Resize the page and I think thats what you are looking for. of course you can mess around with min widths and heights to get them to all look the same.

To have all the buttons on one line modify the `flex-flow: row wrap` to `flex-flow:row no-wrap`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
}
.button4 {
  background:#4e9af1;
  padding: 0.3em 1.0em;
  margin: 0 0.1em 0.4em 0;
  border: 0.15em solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-radius: 3em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0 0.04em 0.04em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  text-align: center;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

a.button4:hover {
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

@media all and (max-width:30em) {
 .container {
  flex-flow: column;
 }

 button4 {
  width: 100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="container">
     <a href="index.html" class="button4">Introduction</a>
     <a href="privacy.html" class="button4">Privacy Policy & Cookies/Security</a>
     <a href="security.html" class="button4">Device Optimisation & Navigation</a>
     <a href="relevant-tech.html" class="button4">Relevant Technologies</a>
     <a href="test-page.html" class="button4">Web technologies</a>
     <a href="bibliography.html" class="button4">Bibliography</a>
  </div>
</div>
```